# ArrayList Declaration - set unknown size

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, size, declaration

I am only in my 8th week of Java, so I am quite new.

I have a class that has an ArrayList object, list. I have another class called TransactionCalc. I would like for TransactionCalc to have its own ArrayList object, called arr3. I need to have be exactly as large as list. I know how to declare an ArrayList that is a size other than 10, but how do you do this if you do not yet know the exact size? Is it possible?

```
public class TransactionCalc extends CalculateAbstract{

    private int count = 0;
    private ArrayList <ItemAttribute> arr3 = new ArrayList <ItemAttribute> (1);
                           //the 1 needs to be list.size() ??
```

I am assuming that in the other class I will need to do public static final int = list.size(), but is it possible to get that constant over to the TransactionCalc class so that it can be in the declaration?

I forgot to add this... since the functionality of arrayList is not really needed, I could also do `list.toArray(arr3)` but that still wouldn't allow for it to be an object of the TransactionCalc class. Is it possible to do that? I'd like to avoid sending the same arr3 over and over again to multiple methods in the same class.

Also, how would I put this as a constructor?

EDIT with help from amaleemur____________

I have updated my code to have:

```
public class FindItemInfo implements InterfacePrint{
    ArrayList <ItemAttribute> list = new ArrayList<ItemAttribute>();
         //load arraylist and do something with it
         //sort arraylist

    public void printPriority(){
        TransactionCalc finish = new TransactionCalc();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){      
            for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++){
                if(arr2.get(i) == list.get(x).getPriority()){
                        finish.cashOut(list.get(x), bankAccount, list.size());   
                }                 //send sorted arr2 to TransactionCalc class
            }
        }

    public static int getListSize(){
        return list.size();
    }
}


public class TransactionCalc {//extends CalculateAbstract{
    private int count = 0;
    //private ArrayList <ItemAttribute> arr3 = new ArrayList <ItemAttribute> (FindItemInfo.getListSize());
    private ItemAttribute[] arr3 = new ItemAttribute[FindItemInfo.getListSize()];

    public void cashOut (ItemAttribute item, double bankAccount, int size) {
        //ItemAttribute[] arr3 = new ItemAttribute[size];

        double runningTotal = 0;
        if((runningTotal + (item.getQuantity()*item.getPrice()))<= bankAccount){
            runningTotal += item.getQuantity()*item.getPrice();
            bankAccount -= runningTotal;
            System.out.format("You will spend $%.2f on " + item.getQuantity() + " of "+ item.getDescription(), runningTotal);
            System.out.format(" and have $%.2f left to spend\n", bankAccount);
        }
        else{
            arr3[count] = item;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

I am making arr3 an object of the TransactionCalc class because it is used for a few methods. The purpose of the array/arraylist is to collect the items that are not being printed. I can use either an array or an arraylist. I initially went with an array but then didn't know the size.

I am now getting static and non-static errors. When I go to try and fix this, it causes more problems.

Comment: I forgot to add this... since the functionality of arrayList is not really needed, I could also do list.toArray(arr3) but that still wouldn't allow for it to be an object of the TransactionCalc class. Is it possible to do that? I'd like to avoid sending the same arr3 over and over again to multiple methods in the same class.

Comment: What is it in this TransactionCalc class that is to be done with this list of yours? Maybe the TransactionCalc can keep methods that you call from the first class? If you dont have any complete code example/stub, at least provide some pseudo code of your different classes.

Comment: You don't need to set the initial size of an `ArrayList,` and rarely want to. Just use the no argument constructor.

Comment: David - I know that it is not necessary. I was getting errors when copying one arraylist into arr3 and Eclipse was saying that arr3 wasn't big enough. Either way, I wanted to learn how I can get an unknown in one class to be used in another. Thumbs up for amaleemur! Even though it isn't yet working I still learned that part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neat thing about using an ArrayList is that you don't have to declare a size.

so this is sufficient and you can add items to the array list.

```
private ArrayList <ItemAttribute> arr3 = new ArrayList <ItemAttribute>();
```

in order to get the size of list, I would suggest doing this:

In your class that contains the ArrayList list, create a method

```
public int getListSize(){

return list.size();

}
```

and now you can safely access the size of list. Does this help?

so now you'd do this:

```
private ArrayList <ItemAttribute> arr3 = 
new ArrayList <ItemAttribute>(otherClass.getListSize());
```

where otherClass is a placeholder for the name of your other class with the ArrayList list.

Comment: alternatively, if list is public in the other class, you could do private ArrayList <ItemAttribute> arr3 = otherClass.list.clone();

Comment: I have tried both as if arr3 was an array and also an arrayList since the arrayList isn't really necessary. both are giving me errors on cannot make a static reference to non-static field list. I am now editing my original question to provide more info.

Comment: @JavaNoob put the full code on paste bin or something g so I can access it and have a better look.

Comment: Is there no constructor for find item info?

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a mutable collection type. This means (in this case) that instances of ArrayList may host arbitrary amounts of elements and in particular, the contained elements of a given instance of ArrayList may change at runtime. So you do not have to declare the amount of elements. In typical cases, you will most likely want to use the default c'tor (=not specify the initial amount of elements). Specifying the initial amount if elements may be a good idea (performance-wise), if you know that there will be a large number of objects inserted at run-time. In such cases, initialising an instance of ArrayList may safe some memory allocations an memcopy operations.